# Removal of an element from a list

Tags: java

I have one list which has one one object. From that object I am taking one value and setting that value to a new different object. After this, I am adding that new object to the list. Now I only need that new object in the list and remove the old object.

```
public void function(List<Activities> listOfActivities)
{
    String name = null;
    for (Activities activities : listOfActivities)
    {
        if (activities instanceOf IndoorGames)
        {
            name = activities.getName();
        }
    }
    Outdoorgames games = new OutdoorGames();
    games.setName(name);

    listOfActivities.add(OutdoorGames);
}
```

Now my list has two objects, I want to remove the old object i.e IndoorGames.

So I did this.

```
ListIterator<Activities> iterator = listOfActivities.listIterator();
while(iterator.hasNext())
{
    Activities a = iterator.next();
    if (a instanceOf IndoorGames)
    {
        iterator.remove(a);
    }
}
```

So Is this a correct approach?

Comment: why don't you do that inside the first for ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `List`'s `set` instead of `add` + `remove` would make more sense in this case:

```
public void function(List<Activities> listOfActivities)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfActivities.size(); i++) {
        Activities activities = listOfActivities.get(i);
        if (activities instanceOf IndoorGames) {
            Outdoorgames games = new OutdoorGames();
            games.setName(activities.getName());
            listOfActivities.set(i,games); // this will replace the
                                           // IndoorGames instance with
                                           // the new Outdoorgames 
                                           // instance
            break;
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ListIterator#set(E)`:

```
for(ListIterator<Activities> it = listOfActivities.listIterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    Activities activities = it.next();
    if(activities instanceof IndoorGames) {
        Outdoorgames games = new OutdoorGames();
        games.setName(activities.getName());
        it.set(games);
    }
}
```